# Unknown key "viaIR"

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, yul

Unknown key "viaIR"
Error HH600: Compilation failed

I'm encountering the above error when I try to compile.

Here is my hardhat.config.ts

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.6.12",
    settings: {
      viaIR: true,
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 2):

`viaIR: true` may require version 0.8.13 and higher.